# Import error: Org.Hibernate.SessionFactory etc

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, gwt

I'm working on a school project which is supposed to be a simple GWT website with Hibernate. I've never used Hibernate or GWT before so for me this is a little tricky.

For starters I've created the website and I've set up a database with XAMPP. After that I followed this guide to set up Hibernate: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-jboss-tools-installation-in-eclipse-mapping-generation-example/

The last thing to do in that example is to generate code. The code is generated but I've got lots of errors due to these

```
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Example;
```

These imports can't be find, anyone knows what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `hibernate` related jars to your eclipse project buildpath.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought all the needed files were added when installing Hibernate.